# Mapping WebView2 to a relative path

Tags: wpf, webview2

I am working on a WPF project (Visual Studio 2022 and Net 6.0). I have local html file within a folder in my project (MyNotices). I have WebView2 in the xaml code as shown below

```
    <DockPanel Width="1200" Height="600" Visibility="Visible" x:Name="web1">
             <wv2:WebView2 x:Name="webView"  Width="{Binding ElementName=CurrentPresenter, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                           Height="{Binding ElementName=CurrentPresenter, Path=ActualHeight}" Source=""/>
    </DockPanel>
```

I would like to map the source of the webview to the local html file. It is working well if I use absolute path to the html file as shown below

```
       await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
       webView.Source = new Uri("/C:/Users/xxxx/source/repos/MyNotices/Local/RichText.html");
```

I would like to use a relative path and I am using the **SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping**
Here is the code

```
  await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(); // ensure the CoreWebView2 is created
          webView.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
            "appassets", "Local", CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.Allow);
             webView.Source = new Uri("http://appassets/RichText.html");
```

Here is the location of my app.exe file
C: \Users\xxxx\source\repos\MyNotices\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\MyNotices.exe.

I get this error message - System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'The system cannot find the path specified. (0x80070003)'. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want a relative path, I think you should copy the folder to your output folder. Then it will be relative (a relative path can't search the whole computer for a match).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You example works assuming the file `Local/RichText.html` is located in the output folder of the `.exe`, i.e. in `C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\MyNotices\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\Local\RichText.html`.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.setvirtualhostnametofoldermapping?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

> For example, after calling `SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping("appassets.example", "assets", CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.Deny);`, navigating to `https://appassets.example/my-local-file.html` will show content from my-local-file.html in the assets subfolder located on disk under the same path as the app's executable file.

So add the `Local/RichText.html` file to your project in Visual Studio and set its `Build Action` property to `Content` and its `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if newer`.

If the file is located outside of your app's output directory you should use an absolute path to access it. The relative path refers to a file within the folder of the `.exe`.

Comment: In my traversing of the web in search of information regarding the problem highlighted in this post, I did not find any documented suggestion that the properties of the target file should be changed in Visual Studio as amply articulated by @mm8. The suggested solution works a charm. Kudos mm8